# Thinking Sphinx connecting to external Sphinx Daemon

Tags: ruby-on-rails, thinking-sphinx

I need to connect my application to external server with Sphinx. Sphinx is used by many applications and I'm not administrating it. What I need to set in my application to connect to that external server with Thinking Sphinx?

I assume I don't run rake ts:start as I'm not using local daemon and I'm not doing any indexing.

I added file thinking_sphinx.yml in my config directory with settings for `address` and `mysql41`. When I try to run search from console I get:

```
User.search('jon', indices: [ 'users' ] ) 
(Object doesn't support #inspect)
 =>
```

Do I need any more settings for Thinking Sphinx to work in my application?

**EDIT:**

I asked Sphinx administrator to change index name to `user_core` so I don't need to specify index. When I run:

```
User.search('jon').first
```

I get:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `constantize' for nil:NilClass
```

Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this Sphinx server set up separately to your local Thinking Sphinx configuration? Thinking Sphinx expects certain attributes to exist in the Sphinx indices (and, as you've discovered, certain naming conventions). It also needs to be using the same data source as your ActiveRecord models.

In short - if the Sphinx configuration isn't generated by Thinking Sphinx, I'd be extremely hesitant to mix it and Thinking Sphinx together.

But otherwise: the full stack trace of the NoMethodError would be useful.

Comment: You were right. There were some differences in attributes. After modifying indexing script with info from generated by Thinking Sphinx config file everything started working. Thanks @pat! :)